# Bash if elif and else doesn't work as it should in my linux script

Tags: linux, bash

My Problem is, the following code throws errors like

```
./sync.sh: Line 25: Syntaxerror at `then [translated to english]
```

My Code is:

```
#!/bin/bash

[...]

if [["$input1" == 1 && "$input2" == 1]]
    then
        #local herunterladen
        echo "Es wird nun local herunterladen"
    elif[["$input1" == 1 && "$input2" == 2]]
    then
        #local hochladen
        echo "Es wird nun local hochgeladen"
    elif [["$input1" == 2 && "$input2" == 1]]
    then
        #online herunterladen
        echo "Es wird nun online herunterladen"
    elif[["$input2" == 2 && "$input2" == 2]]
    then
        #online hochladen
        echo "Es wird nun online hochgeladen"
    else
        echo "${red}Du hast einmal nicht ${green}1${red} oder ${green}2${red} gedrückt!${reset}"
fi
```

My System is Arch Linux with Fish as shell, but I think this deosn't matter.

Comment: Run it through [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need spaces around `[[` and `]]`.

If you read the Bash manual, you'll find that `[[` and `]]` are *reserved words*. Unlike *metacharacters* such as `(` and `)`, they are not detected if they are right next to other ordinary characters.

Answer (score 0):

Check for Bash conditions syntax (ex http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-6.html). 
Bash need spaces before and After [ and ]. Moreover - doubleing of [ and ] is unnecesarry

Comment: It is if you want to use `&&` inside the conditional expression. `[[ ... ]]` is different (and in many ways superior to) `[...]`.